# The Community user does not have a description on RSO

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дух-сообщества

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Normally, the account has a description saying about it's not really a person, and what stuff it does.

Comment: I wish that SE team unify the community user in all sites and add a description [in Klingon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lxmTx.png), just for fun..

Comment: That is because in Russia, Community writes your About section!

Comment: @Won't: sure, we've wrote the About section and even given a new name to the user )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bot's about section seems to have been changed to fix it. This can be marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).